# Count of items returns 0 while it is expected to return 1

Tags: php, jquery

I always will be send to to the `else`.

I have the page `functions.php` with all my functions we are now looking at the function `registerNewAcc()`:

```
<?
function registerNewAcc()
{
  return false;
}
?>
```

Then i got the page `registerHandler.php` where im checking if the function `registerNewAcc() == false`:

```
<?
if (registerNewAcc() == false)
{
  echo '<div class="invisible"></div>';
  echo 'fout';
}
else
{
  echo 'You are register succesfull!<br>Check your e-mail, we have send you an e-mail with a verification-link in it to verify your account.';
}
?>
```

And in my `form.js` file I find the class `.invisible`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var registerStatus = $(data).find(".invisible");
  if (registerStatus.length >= 1) {
    //Kijkt of er regisratie fout is
    $("div.statusBalk").hide().slideDown().css("display", "block").css("background-color", "red").empty().append(data);
    $("span.inputCheck").empty();
    $inputs.prop("disabled", false);
  } else {
    //Kijkt of er regisratie fout is
    $("div.statusBalk").hide().slideDown().css("display", "block").css("background-color", "green").empty().append(data);
    $("span.inputCheck").empty();
    $inputs.prop("disabled", false);
  }
</script>
```

But its always go to the `else` of the js script.
He always display 0 elements found.

I alerted it and it display `0`

[ADDED]

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $( "form#registerForm" ).submit(function( event ) {
    // Stop form from submitting normally
    event.preventDefault();
    var $form = $(this);
    var $url = "registerHandler.php?action=registerCheck";
    var $inputs = $form.find("input");
    var posting = $.post($url, $form.serialize());
    $inputs.prop("disabled", true);
    posting.done(function (data) {
      var formStatus = $(data).find(".inputCheckCross");
      if (formStatus.length >= 1) {
        //Wanneer het formulier fout is
        $("div.registerError").hide().fadeIn().css("display", "block").empty().append(data);
        $("div.statusBalk").css("display", "none");
        $("span.inputCheck").empty();
        $inputs.prop("disabled", false);
      } else {
        var registerStatus = data.find(".invisible");
        if (registerStatus.length >= 1) {
          //Kijkt of er regisratie fout is
          $("div.statusBalk").hide().slideDown().css("display", "block").css("background-color", "red").empty().append(data);
          $("span.inputCheck").empty();
          $inputs.prop("disabled", false);
        } else {
          //Kijkt of er regisratie fout is
          $("div.statusBalk").hide().slideDown().css("display", "block").css("background-color", "green").empty().append(data);
          $("span.inputCheck").empty();
          $inputs.prop("disabled", false);
        }
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

This is the whole js part of what i check.

Comment: spelling error: `invisible`. Sorry if you did it on purpose, I'm just throwing it out there.

Comment: what does `$(data)` represent

Comment: it is the response of `registerHandler.php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the thing, it is weard but it works now.

I had to change the line:

```
//From
if (registerStatus.length >= 1) {
//To
if (registerStatus) {
```

I think its weard because I do this also earlyer on the same way on the line with the data:

```
$(formStatus.length >= 1) {
```

And there it is working.

I think i have a idea why it didn't work but im not sure.
The count elements of .invisible is 1 and its always 1 there are not more of it.
So maybe that is the thing?

Hope you guys have on this a suggestion, leave it in the comments please.

Answer (score 1):

There is something I found,
when I click for the first time on the submit button it shows the green bar
when I click for the second time on the submit button it shows the red bar.

Still dont know what the problem can be :s

Hope this can help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure what you're trying to accomplish with `$(data).find(".invisable")`. Seems like an incorrect selector to me. Try using `$(".invisable").length` instead.

Comment: Tried this, but also not working. I did it on my own way like it is in the post earlyer and that does work. that is why it is so weard.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the misspelling of "invisible" in some places in the code may be your problem.

correct: invisible

incorrect: invisable

Comment: I changed it. refresh to see it ;)

Comment: you changed what? I still see "invisable" in your code after refresh. `echo '<div class="invisable"></div>';`

Comment: Oops forgat that 1 Ghehe

Comment: So are you saying that by editing your post to not include the spelling errors that they are not in your original code and that you are still experiencing problems? because it certainly wouldn't have worked with those errors...please try running your code again after the corrections.

Comment: I didn't say you were stupid. just asking you to confirm what you actually did, which is still not entirely clear...Did your code originally include the misspellings? and if so, did you change your code and verify that the problem you are having is still occurring exactly the same way?

Comment: Ok, I am trying to help you, but you refuse to clearly answer my question, sry I cannot help you then.

Comment: Haha about that stupid thing just messing a little. But yes I checked it all. I always do those things ;)